# Is this sentence pleonastic?

Tags: redundancy

I have this sentence

> People nowadays are so extremely sensitive that they can bear no reproof whatsoever.

My query is, is the author being redundant here by adding ***extremely***? Should we omit it because it is included in the meaning of ***so sensitive***?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word "extremely" changes the emphasis in the question.  It makes it clear that the author considers this type of sensitivity to be "extreme" and not "normal".  So it indicates the opinion of the author about the topic.

It could be removed without much difference in the basic meaning, but it would change the impression that the sentence gives.